# Image Block - upload, resize and post

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress

I recently learnt html, css, javascript, node js. I'm trying to create a blog website as part of the personal project. I want to know as in Wordpress, you can add a block for an image, resize the image and then post it, how to make this functionality as part of my admin page where I can chose to resize image before uploading it.I want to know how to achieve this functionality.  I researched on my own and sadly couldn't get anywhere :(

Comment: CKEditor is one of them as editor as far as i know you can check :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wordpress Documentation itself tells the wordpress users that there is the plugin 'Advanced Custom Fields' for adding new meta fields to your wordpress posts, pages, taxonomies or whatever you like. There is a huge selection of available fields.

ACF Plugin : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

You can use ACF (advanced custom fields) to create a new image block for your post. There also is a crop image field. You can define which image size you would like to have, and on upload, it automatically opens the image crop. Here is the plugin link:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-image-aspect-ratio-crop/

Before you can create your custom image size with putting something like this in your functions.php :
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

So you can create your image size and add an image block to your posts or whatever which opens a crop overlay, so you can easily have your images cropped in the size you like.

If you want to get your ACF meta fields via the Rest-API, i.e. you are using a javascript framework in the frontend, you can also just add all your ACF fields to the rest api:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-to-rest-api/

Hope this helps solving your issue.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful, as I mentioned I just started the back-end part of my journey, but this will help a lot, as I just went through these documentations. You rock.